# Advantages of using Yii rights?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

In addition to creating RbAC file, what is the other advantages of Yii Rights module? What the Yii rights module does that Yii RbAC doesn't support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Allows to manage access in backend: create roles on the fly and attache it to user.
- Role access has weak binding with code because is based on module-controller-action-oriented permissions that you can give to user. That all can be managed with backend interface on the fly.
- Has task (not role) oriented access - when you can create custom task (text editing for example) and base your logic on permissions to tasks instead of roles

Answer (score 1):

You can find answers to all of those questions here: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/

Basically, everything you can do with Rights, you can do with RbAC, but Rights makes it all easier to manage.